# How do I delete the GNUstep folder from home?

Tags: command-line

Recently I installed GNUstep using this command

```
sudo apt-get install gnustep-gui-runtime
```

After I did this I saw this GNUstep folder as in the picture which contains nothing!

So I ran:

```
sudo apt remove gnustep-gui-runtime
```

and the folder is still there, and when I just delete the folder and refresh I see the folder is back again!

[image: see the folder here!]

Comment: Did you try logging out and back in after removing the software? I assume it's still running and creates the folder.

Comment: Okay i will try now.....

Comment: I just remembered I had the exact same problem once and solved it after asking here… -^

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the fact that you removed a software it might very well still be up and running on your system. In this case GNUstep prevents you from removing the directory, so either terminate its process(es) manually or just log out and log in again (or reboot) to be sure it's actually stopped before you remove the folder.

Answer (score 0):

All i did is 
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
Problem solved!